# data_type and UDT_name in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, types

Can anyone help me to find different data_type and corresponding udt_name in postgresql. I tried searching in Internet but no luck. Any reference where I can find it.

Comment: Found info: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2010-10/msg00062.php

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
select data_type,udt_name from information_schema.columns ;
```